# How to create one time EventBridge and set a target to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have been trying to create aws EventBridge one time schedules using code. I tried to create schedule using console and setting target to sqs and it works. Trying to figure out how can I do with code. So here is what I have tried.

```
const eventBridge = new AWS.EventBridge();
try {
  const ruleName = 'my-rules';
  const queueUrl = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3434/myqueue';

  // Create the rule
  const ruleResponse = await eventBridge.putRule({
    Name: ruleName,
    EventPattern: JSON.stringify({
      source: ['my-source'],
    }),
    State: 'ENABLED',
  });
  const twoMinutesFromNow = new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 60 * 1000);
  const utcTime = twoMinutesFromNow.toISOString();

  // Set the target with the desired schedule
  const targetParams = {
    Rule: ruleName,
    Targets: [
      {
        Arn: queueUrl,
        Id: 'my-target-id',
        Input: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello World!' }),
      },
    ],
    ScheduleExpression: utcTime,
  };

  const d = await eventBridge.putTargets(targetParams); 
  return {
    success: 'yes', 
    data : d
  }
} catch (error) {
   return {error}
}
```

This code execute correctly but when I check console, I see nothing in it and there is no data in SQS as well.

Let me know if I am misunderstanding something..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ScheduleExpression will need to be a [chron expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-cron-expressions), and it will go in the putRule call instead of putTargets.

```
 var response = await _amazonEventBridge.PutRuleAsync(
        new PutRuleRequest()
        {
            Description = description,
            EventPattern = eventPattern,
            Name = name,
            ScheduleExpression = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)"
        });
```

There are some examples in a [few languages here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/example_eventbridge_PutRule_section.html).